# Google chrome closes after adding the excel code but works without the excel code

Tags: python, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm pretty new to Python and automation. I'm trying to automate logging in to a web page and add data which I've extracted from excel to a text box on the web page.

Opening the web pages works fine without adding the piece of code below.

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('myExcel.xlsx')
alertNumber = wb.app.selection
```

Before adding the above code chrome opens and goes to every URL and at the final page it stays open untill i click on close, but after adding the above piece of code the chrome closes after executing everyline.

Can someone explain what is missing as Im pretty new to coding.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('myExcel.xlsx')
alertNumber = wb.app.selection

uname = "dummy@example.com"
pword = "Th!s!smydummypa$$w0rd"

supportPortal = "https://url1.com"
openCase = "https://url2.com"
Path = "c:/chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path)

driver.get(supportPortal)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email").send_keys(uname)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "remember-cb").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".submit-btn").click()
print("Username added")

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.ID, "password-sign-in").send_keys(pword)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".submit-btn").click()
print("Password added")

print("Starting to wait")
time.sleep(20)
print("Wait is over")

driver.get(openCase)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "alert_number").send_keys(alertNumber)
```

Comment: Could you post the traceback you are getting?

Comment: Looking at the documentation https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/syntax_overview.html#app-context-manager it might help to use a context manager so the excel instance is closed and cleaned up properly

Comment: Im not getting and error. The code is just fine. But the only which happens is with this code
```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('myExcel.xlsx')
alertNumber = wb.app.selection
```

Gets added to the main code chrome closes. I want to keep it open until I force fully close it.

Comment: Have you tried using the contextmanager approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support, guys. I think I found the answer. webdriver closes the chrome session as soon as it finishes executing the code. Therefore, I added a

```
time.sleep(30)
```

to keep the chrome open until I get sufficeint time to do the changes.